# Not Showing Consent Dialog on EU Countries and Still Get Test Ads

Tags: react-native, admob, firebase-admob

Admob documentation says:

> Ads served by Google can be categorized as personalized or
> non-personalized, both requiring consent from users in the EEA.

However if don't ask consent and set my iOS simulator location to EU country and also use following block on my `App.js`;

```
await AdsConsent.setDebugGeography(AdsConsentDebugGeography.EEA);
```

**I still get test ads on device.**

I'm wondering If I don't show consent dialog to user who is in EU country, they still get non-personalized ads in production?

Comment: Hi, any answer on this?